# Wget and chrome downloads

Tags: wget

While I can download a file putting an HTTP link in Chrome this format

http://someplace.some/get.php?username=myusername&password=mypass&type=m3u_plus&output=ts

if I try the same with wget I have a 404 error

```
wget --user=myusername --password=mypass "http://someplace.some/get.php?type=m3u_plus&output=ts"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you could add the output of the commands you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint expects username and password to be supplied in the query string. wget's `--user` and `--password` options are for using HTTP authentication. They do not set any query string parameters for you. You should just wget the URL as-is instead:

```
wget "http://someplace.some/get.php?username=myusername&password=mypass&type=m3u_plus&output=ts"
```

Comment: Thank you, Ragesh, but your format leads also to a "404- Not Found" response in my Raspbian machine, while the URL downloads a file if I put it in Google Chrome Browser.
Even if I change the User-Agent, the result is a 404

Comment: Think they are filtering, but is not user agent. Not sure how, but they allow VLC/Chrome downloads while barraging wget. Changin the user agend does not improve

Comment: In that case maybe you should look at the network tab in Chrome's dev tools. I don't use Chrome, but in Firefox, I can right click on the request and "Copy as curl" which will give me a complete way to repro the request with curl. Maybe they're looking for some other headers to filter requests. Are you logged in to that site when you try the download? Maybe it's a cookie? I'm just speculating. It's hard to tell without actually looking at the request Chrome is making.